# how can I print user_Id from this array format?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [user_id] => 3
                    )    
            )    
    )
```

I am using Laravel 8. I want to fetch single data and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use `print_r` to dump your records. kindly use `dd()` or `dump()`. So you have a clear idea about collections. So as of now, you fetch as

```
$yourCollection->first()->user_id
```

if you have multiple models you can use loops.

Comment: I am new to laravel. Please tell me what is my collection? is it my model/table name? thanks.

Comment: It's your dumped object. so I think you dump object in `print_r()`. just replace that `object` with `$yourCollection` and let me know the results.

Comment: $user_id = DB::table('order_details')->select('user_id')->where(['order_details.id' => $id])->first()->user_id;
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($user_id);
            die();

Comment: thank you. I got the value.